# Convert string to byte using Byte.Parse Method

Tags: c#

```
   private byte CalculateChecksum(byte[] realbytesend)
        {
            int checksum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < realbytesend.Length ; i++)
            {
                string strchecksum = realbytesend.GetValue(i).ToString();
                int intchecksum = Convert.ToInt32(strchecksum);
                checksum += intchecksum;
            }
            string csumbit = checksum.ToString("X"); //Gives you hexadecimal
            string checksumbit = string.Format("0x{0}", csumbit);

            style = NumberStyles.HexNumber;

            bytechecksum = Byte.Parse(checksumbit, style);
            return bytechecksum;
        }
```

when i debug this code, there is an error message with
' System.FormatException:"The input string is malformed." '
i dont know why it happen.

i already tried convert.ToByte and byte.parse(string), but i dont know why it doesnt work!!

i want you to help me...

Comment: That is a very complicated way of calculating a checksum.  But, your `checksum` variable is an integer, and very likely greater than 0xff (the max value for a byte).  What do you expect Byte.Parse(checksumbit, style) to do with a number that size?  What is the point of all the conversions to and from a string?  Why not calculate a sum (or do some XOR operations) and then mask the result with `0xff`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of problems with your code. However, the main problem is you are playing *Conversion-Football* from `string` to `int` to `byte`. Don't do that.. Instead, keep it simple.

Your method can be boiled down to the following

```
private byte CalculateChecksum(byte[] realbytesend)
{
   byte checksum = 0;
   unchecked // allow overflows
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < realbytesend.Length; i++)
         checksum += realbytesend[i];
   }
   return checksum;
}
```

---

or `foreach`

```
...

unchecked // allow overflows
{
   foreach (var b in realbytesend)
      checksum += b;
}

...
```

---

or *Linq*

```
private byte CalculateChecksum(byte[] realbytesend)
  => realbytesend.Aggregate((sum, i) => unchecked((byte)(sum + i)));
```

---

[unchecked (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked)

> The unchecked keyword is used to suppress overflow-checking for
>   integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.